# Uninstall mysql on Lion?

Tags: mysql

Im currently using MAMP, but I installed the Mysql standalone before. So how can I uninstall that mysql and make sure it doesn't affect on the MAMP MySQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Use the following list of commands to remove MySQL from OSX Lion :

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Finally edit `/etc/hostconfig` and remove the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-`